# How to generate numbers from 01 to 10 python

Tags: python, random

When I execute this code:

```
month = random.randint(1, 12)
```

and I get a number below 10, its without a 0 at the start. For an example, it generates 5. I don't want it to be 5, I want it to be 05

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

try this it is nice and short.

```
i = 5
print(f"{i:02}")
```

output:

```
05
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.zfill()` here.

```
num = random.randint(1, 12)
num = str(num).zfill(2)
print(num)

05
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
print(f"{random.randint(1, 12):02}")
```

Execution:

```
In [1]: print(f"{random.randint(1, 12):02}")
11
In [2]: print(f"{random.randint(1, 12):02}")
02
In [3]: print(f"{random.randint(1, 12):02}")
10
In [4]: print(f"{random.randint(1, 12):02}")
01
```